# Flutter Grid view with dynamic width and height

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, flutter-layout

My issue is that I want to display Text widget in my grid view and each one of these widgets has its own content and can have different width, I am facing trouble with achieving that…

[image]

this is widgets don't show the content of its child

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For this case, you can use `Wrap` widget.

```dart
Padding( //outer spacing
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: Wrap(
    spacing: 8, // space between items
    children: ["Java", "Nodejs"]
        .map((e) => Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
              ),
              child: Text(e),
            ))
        .toList(),
  ),
)
```

More about [`Wrap widget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html).

Comment: man you just saved my life

Comment: Glad to help you out, you can accept as answer while it solves your issue, you can find more about [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Doesn't really solve the issue as wrap has different sizes. Would be nice to use gridview as it looks better design wise.

Comment: @OliverDixon you may right but the question is *Grid view with dynamic width and height*

Comment: @YeasinSheikh just setting width on wrap has the same effect ;_)

Comment: It will be easier if you ask a new question by providing minimal snippet, Then I might be able to get it.