# can I create a gridview with dynamic width of cells?

Tags: flutter, gridview, layout, flutter-dependencies

I tried using "flutter staggered grid view", though I managed to make their width different. However, in the end, they are still all "squared" and not really different or unique from one another.

1. I tried using Staggered fit but only ended up making them all the same
2. using extent makes no difference

Problem to fix:
is there a way in flutter to create a gridview with its items having dynamic width and for height being dynamic is optional.
presume the data youll receive is a string coming from db how would I make it work with staggeredgridview or any other way?

here is an image of what Im trying to accomplish

[image: this is what Im trying to solve]

Comment: Checkout this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71820197/flutter-grid-view-with-dynamic-width-and-height